# recursive menu with that data structure

Tags: php, recursion, menu

i am learning about recursion, and here is the menu array, i have search a lot and not found the solution with that menu structure.

Any one can help with these.

```
$menu = array(
    'level' => array(
        0 => 1
        1 => 1
        2 => 2
        3 => 3
        4 => 1
        5 => 2
        6 => 2
        7 => 3
        8 => 2
    ),
    'title' => array(
        0 => title 1
        1 => title 2
        2 => title 3
        3 => title 4
        4 => title 5
        5 => title 6
        6 => title 7
        7 => title 8
        8 => title 9
    )
)
```

how to produce following html structure with recursion?

```
<ul>
    <li>title 1</li>
    <li>title 2
        <ul>
            <li>title 3
                <ul>
                    <li>title 4</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>title 5
        <ul>
            <li>title 6</li>
            <li>title 7
                <ul>
                    <li>title 8</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>title 9</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is the level for?

Comment: I don't see how the html struct has any relation with the array you have provided. How can we tell a item has sub items?

Comment: Ok I now understand, where the structure comes from.

Comment: Can the level have more then 3? Or is the maximum always 3 sub categories?

Comment: yes, can be more than 3, so i want to use recursion, thanks for your comments

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i merged the structure and levels. a recursive function creates the output. 
i think this code is easy understandable - no need for comments.
the structure just take the first element of a array as title and increase the level.

```
<?php
$menu = [
    'title 1',
    [
        'title 2',
        [
            ['title 3',
            'title 4']
        ]
    ],
    [
        'title 5',
            'title 6',
            ['title 7',
            'title 8'],
            'title 9'
    ]
];

function createMenu($menu,$entry = false,$level = 1) {
    foreach ($menu as $title) {
        if (is_array($title)) {
                createMenu($title,true,$level);
                if (count($title)>1) {
                echo str_repeat("\t",$level*2-1)."\t</ul>\n";
                echo str_repeat("\t",$level*2-1)."</li>\n";
                }
        } else {
            echo str_repeat("\t",$level*2-1)."<li>$title";
            if ($entry) {
                echo "\n".str_repeat("\t",$level*2-1)."\t<ul>\n";
                $level++;
                $entry = false;
            } else {
                echo "</li>\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
echo "<ul>\n";
createMenu($menu);
echo "</ul>";
```

---

solution 2 stuck to your question even if i dont recomend it:

```
<?php
$menu = array(
    'level' => [1,1,2,3,1,2,2,3,2],
    'title' => ["title 1","title 2","title 3","title 4","title 5","title 6","title 7","title 8","title 9"]
);
echo "<ul>\n";
//cycle levels
$lastLevel = 1;
foreach ($menu['level'] as $key => $level) {
    if ($key == 0) {}
    elseif ($level > $lastLevel) echo "\n".str_repeat("\t",$lastLevel*2)."<ul>\n";
    elseif ($level < $lastLevel) {
        echo "</li>\n";
        for (;$level<$lastLevel;$lastLevel--) {
            echo str_repeat("\t",($lastLevel-1)*2)."</ul>\n";
            echo str_repeat("\t",($lastLevel-1)*2-1)."</li>\n";
        }
    } else echo "</li>\n";
    echo str_repeat("\t",$level*2-1).'<li>'.$menu['title'][$key];
    $lastLevel = $level;
}
echo "</li>\n";
//finish tags
for (;1 < $lastLevel;$lastLevel--) {
    echo str_repeat("\t",($lastLevel-1)*2)."</ul>\n";
    echo str_repeat("\t",($lastLevel-1)*2-1)."</li>\n";
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @di3 helli di3, thanks for your answer, but i cannot understand how the array become your merged array, can you give more detail? or base on my array to code it? thanks so much

Comment: i use the structure of the array for the levels. level one is the first array dimension evey following dimension is another level. the first entry of the array is the title of a new dimension. you are more flexible with that

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but how to apply your code to my array structure? Your array is multiple array, and mine is 1d array, i get confuse and seems hard to apply it.

Comment: edited a 2. solution.  it requires a valid array no checks possible. and there is no recursion. both are same output solution one is much more flexible and the array of 2. can have errors by the user which will produce invalid output

Comment: yes, i know invalid menu structure will produce invalid output.
solution 2 working for me, thanks so much

Comment: personaly i still prefer multi dimensional array structure containing position and title at once. you are much more flexible with that. you have to change all values if you want to insert a title somewhere or change the levels. but nvm your welcome.

Comment: @AndreFerraz what did you do ?